# Is "membership to an organisation" wrong?

Tags: prepositions

I have been seeing increasing use of "membership **to** an organisation" (club, association etc.). The "to" makes my teeth grate, as I have always used "of". Should I continue to resist (I run a large membership organisation!) or give in and let my teeth wear down to the roots?

For example, I received an email headed "Membership to the XXX from Jan 1 2019 - Guidelines for Press Releases, Media, Websites etc" about our recent membership of an organisation and how we should communicate it in the press and online. I can think of more complex formulations where "to" would be appropriate. For example, "He attributed the success of his membership to the Mason's Chapter to which he belonged". These are somewhat forced examples, not simple references to X belonging to Y. My hope is that the simple statement "It is admirable that X is a member of Y", should never be legitimately appear as "It is admirable that X is a member to Y" nor be rewritten as "X's membership to Y is admirable", both of which usages I now see more frequently and strongly dislike (but perhaps I am wrong).

Comment: *I am a* ***member of*** *an organization.* But *I have a* ***membership to*** *an organization.* There is nothing at all wrong with *membership to*. You certainly would not say that you have a *membership of*, nor would you say that you are a *member to*.

Comment: I am reaching the conclusion that this is a British/US English difference. A post on this site in August 2016 reached the same conclusion. Two examples. The Oxford & Cambridge Club (London) website says "...to apply for membership **of** the Club..."  Princeton Club of New York has "...to apply for membership **to** The Princeton Club of New York". BrE "of" usage appears in the Cambridge Dictionary - no reference either way in Miriam Webster. As Jason Bassford (US?) would never use "membership of", so I would never use "membership to". Both are correct, depending on your variety of English.

Comment: I see I should have included the reference @JasonBassford in my previous comment. BTW, I now also see from your profile that you are Canadian and not from the US - sorry!  I guess I should refer in this case to American rather than US English, even knowing that there are important usage differences between the US and Canada. Please forgive this newbie's mistakes!